# Sharing files with nanohttpd in android

Tags: java, android, wifi-direct, nanohttpd

i need to develop an android app, a chat app, in which the two devices should be connected via wifi direct and share files via nanohttpd.
can anyone share a guide for this ?

Comment: A tutorial for what? A guide for what?

Comment: @blackapps share files between 2 devices using nanohttpd

Comment: It is unclear which info you need.

Comment: @blackapps i need to develop an android app, a chat app, in which the two devices should be connected via wifi direct and share files via nanohttpd. i need a guide on how to approach and what to do.

Comment: You told nothing new. Well sharing files became chatting but ala.. We already knew that. You should come to the point and tell which difficulties you have. This is a coding side. We help you with your code.